# Two searchable.xml activities in one AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, search, android-manifest, searchable

I have an Android app which has a few different activities for browsing articles and images downloaded from RSS.

I'd like to be able to offer to hook up the [search button to the Search dialog](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), using the a `searchable.xml` file. I've managed to do this with one search, using:

```
<activity android:name=".search.SearchResultsActivity"
    android:label="@string/search_results_activity_title" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable_articles"/>
</activity>
```

and in the `<application />`

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".search.SearchResultsActivity" />
```

I can now launch the Search dialog from any activity, and it launches the `SearchResultsActivity`.

I would now like to be able to search for images when the user is an `ImageListActivity`, using a `searchable_images.xml`, and use the default everywhere else.

I have a `SearchResultsImageActivity` which includes the following meta-data element, and used the same element in the `ImageListActivity`.

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable_images"/>
```

On pressing the search button in the `ImageListActivity`, I get the default search from `searchable_articles.xml`.

If I change the `default_searchable` to `SearchResultsImageActivity`, the image search is always launched, and the article search is never launched.

If I remove the `default_searchable` meta-data element altogether, and add `searchable` meta-data only selected activities, no search is launched.

I'm fairly sure this should be possible, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: I don't think you can do it using xml since the resource is a one to one with an Intent. You might be able to switch out the resource in you code.

Answer (score 5):

In your `Manifest` file update the `ImageListActivity` activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".ImageListActivity"
    ...

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".SearchResultsImageActivity" />
</activity>
```

So when you will trigger native search in `ImageListActivity` it will invoke the `SearchResultsImageActivity` and default one for others.

Assuming `SearchResultsImageActivity` is `searchable`.

Answer (score 1):

One way I did this was to create fake activities then switch out the activities when you need them.

```
<activity android:name="activitySearchMain" />
  <activity android:name="activitySearchSub1">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
      <data android:scheme="user" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="activitySearchSub2">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.sample.twitter.action.SEARCH" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
      <data android:scheme="user" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Create two class that are named for the sub activities.

then create intents like this when component is clicked...

```
Intent sourceIntent = getIntent();
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, activitySearchSub2.class);
newIntent.setAction(activitySearchSub2.ACTION2);
newIntent.setData(sourceIntent.getData());
startActivity(newIntent);
finish();
```

and call the intents from onClick when a button is clicked or some other component is click:

Comment: I've not come across this activity within an activity pattern. I'm not clear what this is doing.

Comment: Its a way to switch out activities when clicking buttons but allowing you to keep the main activity in the background.  Useful when doing searches on a document from say an RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the search function in just that activity, it should prevent the search call from going up to the application level.  The return value controls if the call is propagated up.

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    onPromptSearch();
    return false;  // don't go ahead and show the search box
}
```