# Add search interface in TabView

Tags: android, search, listview, tabs

I'd like to add search interface in TabView.

I read this document. But it is not enough information for me. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html

It should be added in TabView and The suggestion data is JSON from web server. (I don't know how to get data using URI)

I'd like to get informations like example codes, blog posts, manual... etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967017/two-searchable-xml-activities-in-one-androidmanifest-xml) I answered, so this may help you.  If you are looking for a custom webservice searcher then you need to do this more on the webservice side to accept wildcards and such for your queries.  I'd look at [SRU VIA HTTP SOAP](http://www.loc.gov/standards/sru/specs/transport.html#soap)...